# Charles proxy localhost to https

Tags: curl, soap, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm trying to proxy a curl soap request using Charles web proxy.

```
curl \
  --header "Host: https://soapapi.com" \
  --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" \
  --header "SOAPAction: http://soapapi.com/RequestAction" \
  --data "@/request-v2.0.6.xml" http://localhost:8888/cta/sys2/soap11/endpoint-v2-0
```

Which results in `http://https://soapapi.com/cta/sys2/soap11/endpoint-v2-0`.

Is there a way to proxy to https through localhost? Maybe replacing protocol and domain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a way. There is a rewrite option.

In the Host: header remove the protocol. And proxy to http://localhost:8888

Under **Tools** menu there is a rewrite option. This opens the rewrite window.

[image]